# Alamofire type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: json, xcode, swift, get, alamofire

I know theres multiple questions with the same topic, though the difference between my question and those seem to be defining parameters. Whats even odder is the code would build and install on my iPhone until yesterday.

This is where Xcode complains

```
private class func getLocItemsAtPath(path: String!, completionHandler: (LocItemsWrapper?, NSError?) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, path!)
        .responseLocItemsArray { response in
            if let error = response.result.error
            {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }
            completionHandler(response.result.value, nil)
    }
}
```

Here is the entire class

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

enum LocItemFields: String {
    case Name = "name"
    case LocationBackground = "locationBackground"
    case Logo = "logo"
    case Status = "status"
    case Company = "company"
    case Id = "id"
    case Url = "url"
}

class LocItemsWrapper {
    var locItems: Array<LocItems>?
    var count: Int?
    private var next: String?
    private var previous: String?
}

class LocItems {
    var idNumber: Int?
    var name: String?
    var locationBackground: String?
    var logo: String?
    var status: String?
    var company: String?
    var id: String?
    var url: String?

    required init(json: JSON, id: Int?) {
        //print(json)
        self.idNumber = id
        self.name = json[LocItemFields.Name.rawValue].stringValue
        self.locationBackground = json[LocItemFields.LocationBackground.rawValue].stringValue
        self.logo = json[LocItemFields.Logo.rawValue].stringValue
        self.status = json[LocItemFields.Status.rawValue].stringValue
        self.company = json[LocItemFields.Company.rawValue].stringValue
        self.id = json[LocItemFields.Id.rawValue].stringValue
    }

    // MARK: Endpoints
    class func endpointForLocItems(long: Double!, lat: Double!) -> String {
        return Constants.getLocLoadListUrl() + "/" + String(long) + "/" + String(lat) + "/0"
    }

    private class func getLocItemsAtPath(path: String!, completionHandler: (LocItemsWrapper?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, path!)
            .responseLocItemsArray { response in
                if let error = response.result.error
                {
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                    return
                }
                completionHandler(response.result.value, nil)
        }
    }

    class func getLocItems(long: Double, lat: Double, completionHandler: (LocItemsWrapper?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        getLocItemsAtPath(LocItems.endpointForLocItems(long,lat: lat), completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    class func getMoreLocItems(wrapper: LocItemsWrapper?, completionHandler: (LocItemsWrapper?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        if wrapper == nil || wrapper?.next == nil
        {
            completionHandler(nil, nil)
            return
        }
        getLocItemsAtPath(wrapper!.next!, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}

extension Alamofire.Request {
    func responseLocItemsArray(completionHandler: Response<LocItemsWrapper, NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<LocItemsWrapper, NSError> { request, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                return .Failure(error!)
            }
            guard let responseData = data else {
                let failureReason = "Array could not be serialized because input data was nil."
                let error = Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                return .Failure(error)
            }

            let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
            let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, responseData, error)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(value)
                let wrapper = LocItemsWrapper()
                wrapper.next = json["next"].stringValue
                wrapper.previous = json["previous"].stringValue
                wrapper.count = json["count"].intValue

                var allLocItems:Array = Array<LocItems>()
                //print(json)
                let results = json["rows"]
                //print(results)
                for jsonLocItems in results
                {
                    //print(jsonLocItems.1)
                    let locItems = LocItems(json: jsonLocItems.1, id: Int(jsonLocItems.0))
                    allLocItems.append(locItems)
                }
                wrapper.locItems = allLocItems
                return .Success(wrapper)
            case .Failure(let error):
                return .Failure(error)
            }
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer,
            completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

EDIT: I got rid of the error by changing LocItemsWrapper? to LocItemsWrapper! but now I have an error saying ambiguous use of .responseLocItemsArray...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode is trying to tell you that it can't figure out which .responseLocItemsArray to use, check all your other classes to see if you used it anywhere else.

Comment: That fixed it, Thank you so much